# How to read this capacitor

Tags: capacitor

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjF4e.jpg

This is in a 2004 manufactured motherboard, Sanyo brand capacitor

Can anyone help me identify the mf rating and volt. And why it’s written like this[image]

Comment: Please add more clear pictures. you can try to cover complete text on the capacitors in the frame

Comment: Please click on the link to zoom , it’s high res image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Top right corner, 620uF 6.3V,
- Left, 750uF 4V

As to why I read it that way, there are a few hints, first it is a motherboard, so it won't have multiple hundreds of volts, next low capacity high voltage capacitors are much larger than high capacity low voltage capacitors,

Comment: Also: capacitance is usually from E24 series (which has 6.2 and 7.5, but not 4 or 6.3), while voltage is from R5 series (which has 4.0 and 6.3). This further confirms which value is which.